# Write EPIPE error when filling form using node-pdftk

Tags: pdftk, epipe

I am trying to fill a pdf form using nodejs.

Im trying to use node-pdftk package for the same.Did following steps:

Installed pdftk for windows
mapped the path to the environment variables PATH
installed node-pdf package

```
`const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const cors = require('cors')
const pdftk = require('node-pdftk');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer'); // v1.0.5
var upload = multer();

app.listen(8000, () => {
console.log('Server started!')
});
var pdfPath='OoPdfFormExample.pdf';
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));
var formdata = {
'Given Name': 'Swetha',
'Family Name': 'Gulapannavar'
}
app.post('/api/file', upload.array(), (req, res, next) => {
//var buffer=JSON.stringify(Buffer.from(req.body));
var buffer=Buffer.from(req.body)
    pdftk
    .input(pdfPath)
    .fillForm(formdata)
    .flatten()
    .output()
    .then(buffer => {
        // Still returns a buffer
        res.type('application/pdf'); // If you omit this line, file will 
download
        res.send(buf);
        })
    .catch(err => {
        res.send(err.message)
        // handle errors
    });
});`
```

but i'm getting following error when i try to execute the same.
Write EPIPE error.

Comment: Do you have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by node-pdftk not being able to find the PDFtk binaries; your PATH variable may not be set correctly for the account running your web service. You can set the bin path directly inside of your application using node-pdftk's configure function, which is briefly described on the node-pdftk npm [project page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-pdftk). If that doesn't work, try configuring the tempDir path.